# Weld @Produces dependency has null injection point

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a generic DAO with a non default constructor that looks something like this (not actually to do with vehicles I'm just trying to provide a simple example)

```
public class GenericVehicleDao<T extends Vehicle> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    @Inject
    private DaoHelper daoHelper;

    public GenericDao(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

I have another class with some @Produces methods which uses this constructor so for example

```
public class AppProducer {

    @Produces
    public GenericDao<Car> createCar() {
        return new GenericDao(Car.class);
    }

    @Produces
    public GenericDao<Truck> createTruck() {
        return new GenericDao(Truck.class);
    }

}
```

I can then inject that DAO into a service layer eg.

```
@Stateless
public class VehicleService {

    @Inject
    private GenericVehicleDao<Car> carDao;

}
```

That Car DAO injects fine into the service layer, however I'm finding that the DAO's injected `DaoHelper` is null after the DAO has been constructed. If I inject the DaoHelper into the service layer then that injects fine, I'd rather do the injection in the DAO itself however. I have tried switching from field injection to setter injection but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again answering my own question, this may be useful to others. After some more Googling I spotted the following in the [Weld documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html#d0e3332)

> There's one potential problem with the code above. The implementations
>   of CreditCardPaymentStrategy are instantiated using the Java new
>   operator. Objects instantiated directly by the application can't take
>   advantage of dependency injection and don't have interceptors.
>
> If this isn't what we want, we can use dependency injection into the
>   producer method to obtain bean instances:

What this means is I can change my Producer methods to take the following format and then it works fine

```
@Produces
public GenericDao<Car> createCar(DaoHelper helper) {
    GenericDao<Car> carDao = new GenericDao<>(Car.class);
    carDao.setHelper(helper);
    return carDao;
}
```

Comment: Just a confirmation - this is right, when you handle object creation yourself, no field can be automatically injected into. There are ways of achieving that, such as making it an `InjectionTarget`, but what you did is the easiest and a go-to approach. Also +1 for actually reading the docs :)